# How can i pass 3 parameters in onclick function .The parameters are inside php tag

Tags: javascript, php, function, yii, hidden-field

This is my onclick function:

```
onclick="InboxDetailsPage('<?php echo $message['id']; ?>')
```

These are my parameters: `threadid`,`recipient id`, and `message id`

```
<input type="hidden" id="threadId-<?php echo $message['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $message['threadId']; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" id="recipientId-<?php echo $message['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $message['otherUserRoleId']; ?>"/>
<?php echo $message['id']; ?>
```

This is where i am using my onclick function:

```
<div class="inbox">
    <?php $inboxno = 0;
    foreach ($messageList as $message) { ?>
        <?php if ($message['toFromLabel'] == "From") {
            $inboxno++; ?>
            <input type="hidden" id="threadId-<?php echo $message['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $message['threadId']; ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="recipientId-<?php echo $message['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $message['otherUserRoleId']; ?>"/>
            <tr class="gradeA odd inbox">
                <td class="" style="padding-bottom: 1px;" <?php if ($message['status'] == MessageStatusEnum::UNREAD){ ?>style="color:#E55B43;" <?php } else { ?>style="color:#000;" <?php }; ?>><?php echo $message['date']; ?></td>
                <td class="" style="padding-bottom: 1px;" <?php if ($message['status'] == MessageStatusEnum::UNREAD){ ?>style="color:#E55B43;" <?php } else { ?>style="color:#000;" <?php }; ?>><?php echo $message['fromName']; ?></td>
                <td class=" " style="padding-bottom: 1px;" <?php if ($message['status'] == MessageStatusEnum::UNREAD){ ?>style="color:#E55B43;" <?php } else { ?>style="color:#000;" <?php }; ?> style="width:300px !important"><?php echo $message['subject'] ?></td>
                <td class="" style="padding-bottom: 1px;"><a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalq1" class="btn btn-success " onclick="InboxDetailsPage('<?php echo $message['id']; ?>') ">VIEW</a></td>
            </tr>
        <?php }
    } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Please help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the below format:

```
onclick="InboxDetailsPage('<?php echo $message['id'];?>', '<?php echo $message['id'];?>', '<?php echo $message['id'];?>')
```

**Alternatively**, using just one echo:

```
onclick="InboxDetailsPage(<?php echo "'{$message['id']}', '{$message['date']}', '{$message['id']}'";?>)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method:

```
    <a href="#" onclick="myFunction('parameter1', 'parameter', 'parameter3');">click me</a>
<script>
    function myFunction(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3) {
      alert(parameter1);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show me what is my error? I will like know it, this could help me.

Comment: parameters you have to pass are php vars not strings,

Comment: I think your comment is superfluous, but thanks for that, it's not sarcasm.

Comment: well if you think its unnecessary then cant do much.

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick="InboxDetailsPage(
    '<?php echo $message['id'];?>', 
    '<?php echo $message['id'];?>', 
    '<?php echo $message['id'];?>'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to JSON encode the array of options, and send parameters  so that the long parameter list is avoided and readability is preferred.

```
$params=[
   'thread_id'=>$message['thread_id'],
   'recipient_id'=>$message['recipient_id'],
   'id'=>$message['id']
];

<input type="text" onclick="InboxDetailsPage('<?=json_encode($params)?>')">
```

and then use it

```
function InboxDetailsPage(options){
     console.log(options.thread_id,options.recipient_id,options.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
onclick="InboxDetailsPage("<?php echo $message['id'];?>","threadId-<?php echo $message['id']; ?>","recipientId-<?php echo $message['id']; ?>")
```